# Can we use Web-bluetooth between two browsers on different devices be able to chat or exchange data?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

i want to make two browsers in two different devices be able to chat via web bluetooth. Lets say i load a website on both devices and if in the case internet is lost i still want both the devices be able to chat?

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid that's not possible. At least not in the general sense. Web Bluetooth [Draft Community Group Report](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/) states:

> The first version of this specification allows web pages, running on a
>   UA in the Central role, to connect to GATT Servers over either a
>   BR/EDR or LE connection.

Both browsers will be GATT *Clients* and needs a GATT *Server* to connect to. You can't provide a GATT Server via the Web Bluetooth API.

Comment: FYI there is an experimental GATT server API now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BluetoothRemoteGATTServer